# Increasing docker volume size using docker-compose

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I'm working on deploying a Flask web app with Docker (using docker-compose). Users upload files which can be particularly big (>1GB). My question is -- do I have to be worried about the container running out of space? I've read that containers have a default max size of 10GB, and I will definitely exceed that quickly. If I create a volume in the "flask-app/uploads" directory where all the files are stored, does that solve my problem or is the volume just another container with the same size limitations? Is there any way I can just store everything that gets uploaded to "flask-app/uploads" to the host machine so nothing get written to the container?
Here is my docker-compose.yml file for reference:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/flask-app/static
    - /usr/src/flask-app/uploads     (??)
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 app:app

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

data:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  command: "true"

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes_from:
    - data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: is this the only way to do it? https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/01/29/docker-device-mapper-resize/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, this is a common practice, you can use a host volume. Change the volume line to `- ./uploads:/usr/src/flask-app/uploads`.